# Grails - Creating a custom PersistenceEventListener

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.3.8. I want to add two audit fields(createdBy and lastUpdatedBy) to some domains. So taking the idea from [audit plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging), I created a custom Listener.

```
package com.nimbus.listener

import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.Datastore
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEvent
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.PreInsertEvent
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.PreUpdateEvent
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent

@Log4j
class NimbusStampListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {

    public NimbusStampListener(final Datastore datastore) {
        super(datastore)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPersistenceEvent(final AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
        if (event.source != this.datastore) {
            log.trace("Event received for other datastore. Ignoring event")
            return
        }

        if (event instanceof PreInsertEvent) {
            beforeInsert(event.getEntity(), event.getEntityAccess())
        } else if (event instanceof PreUpdateEvent) {
            beforeUpdate(event.getEntity(), event.getEntityAccess())
        }
    }

    public boolean supportsEventType(Class<? extends ApplicationEvent> eventType) {
        return PreInsertEvent.class.isAssignableFrom(eventType) ||
                PreUpdateEvent.class.isAssignableFrom(eventType)
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

and registering it inside plugin:

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
    application.mainContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { key, datastore ->
            com.nimbus.NimbusStampListener listener = new com.nimbus.NimbusStampListener(datastore, application)
            applicationContext.addApplicationListener(listener)
        }
}
```

The listener is being registered successfully and it also listen to Persistence Events. The problem is when I try to fetch `entity` or `entityAccess` fields on `event` object, they are null.

But I can fetch `event.entityObject` field and I can work with this. But sometimes while creating a new auditable object, values for createdBy and lastUpdatedBy are not set on insertion, rather they triggers a new update event which modifies the object version causing `StaleObjectStateException` in other parts of the project.

`AbstractPersistenceEvent` class has two constructors.

```
protected AbstractPersistenceEvent(final Datastore source, final PersistentEntity entity,
        final EntityAccess entityAccess) {
    super(source);
    this.entity = entity;
    this.entityAccess = entityAccess;
    this.entityObject = entityAccess.getEntity();
}

protected AbstractPersistenceEvent(final Datastore source, final Object entity) {
    super(source);
    entityObject = entity;
    this.entity = null;
    this.entityAccess = null;
}
```

So its clear that my listener receives the event object which is being created from second constructor. Grails has also some inbuilt listeners such as `AutoTimestampEventListener` , which updates timestamp fields(`dateCreated & lastUpdated`) in a domain automatically. This listener works using entity and entityAccess objects, that means they are not null there.

When I tried to print all listeners registered through applicationContext using `applicationContext.applicationEventMulticaster.applicationListeners`, it doesn't contain the `AutoTimestampEventListener`.

It would be great if someone can help me how to make entity and entityAccess available inside my custom listener or point where could I find how the `AutoTimestampEventListener` is being registered. I couldn't find it in grails source code either shipped with the distribution.

Comment: What are you doing inside `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` methods?

Comment: I'll update createdBy and lastUpdatedBy fields there depending upon the event type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found some ways to achieve my requirements and thought to share it with others. I have created two blogs describing the options that worked for me. It doesn't make sense to post whole blog here so I'm just going to give the little idea about the options.

1. **Option 1**: Hook into `GormInstanceApi` and override its methods and there implement your logic to update the domain fields.
2. **Option 2**: Instead of using Grails events in Persistence Listener directly, fetch native Hibernate event from them which allow you to update the current state of an event.

Blog links for more detailed explanation:

[Using Hibernate Events with PersistenceEventListener](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-hibernate-events-with-persistenceeventlistener/)

[Hooking into the Instance methods of the GORM API](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/hooking-into-the-instance-methods-of-the-gorm-api/)